# Check if any array in list of arrays is within range of another array

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a list of lists of length k and am trying to find how many have all elements at the same index within 500 of each other. For example:

```
intervals = [[9000, 10000, 11000], [11000, 10250, 13000], [9250, 9750, 11250], [11000, 10500, 14000]]
```

Should return

```
unique = [[11000, 10250, 13000], [11000, 10500, 14000]]
```

because for the list at index 0 and index 2 contain all elements within 500 of each other, while the others do not contain all elements within 500 of another list.

```
def unique(intervals, k):
    unique = []
    for i in range(len(intervals)):
        l = intervals[:i] + intervals[i+1:] 
        t = intervals[i]
        n = 0
        if ((np.array(l) >= np.array(t) - 500) & (np.array(l) <= np.array(t) + 500)).all(1).any():
            n += 1
        if n == 0:
            unique.append(intervals[i])
    return unique
```

The issue with my function is that using large datasets, the runtime is extremely slow and inefficient.

Comment: Are the inner list always of 3 elements?

Comment: No, I should have specified that the lists are of length k

Comment: But all the lists are the same size

Comment: None of the sublists in `intervals` have all elements within 500 of each other.

Comment: @DaniMesejo yes

Comment: Why is `[9000, 10000, 11000]` not part of the output? just to better understand the problem

Comment: @DaniMesejo I guess I didn't explain well. The lists at index 0 and 2 have all of their elements within 500 of EACH OTHER'S elements at the same index. 9000 is within 500 of 9250, 10000 is within 500 of 9750, 11000 is within 500 of 11250

Comment: Are these lists of lists or lists of arrays (e.g. numpy)? Not that it would make much of a difference, but best to use accurate terminology

Comment: @PranavHosangadi the input is originally lists, but I convert them into numpy arrays in the function as I believe it makes it easier to compare individual elements. Converting them every loop may contribute to the inefficiency though.

Comment: @DaniMesejo Hi dani, I was wondering if you would be able to take a look at my comment on your answer

Comment: @DaniMesejo I left an example down below, thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

One approach that is `O(nlogn)` where `n` is the number of intervals:

```
import numpy as np

intervals = [[9000, 10000, 11000],
             [11000, 10250, 13000],
             [9250, 9750, 11250],
             [11000, 10500, 14000]]

# sort each column 
res = [np.array(sorted(e)) for e in zip(*intervals)]

lookup = []
for arr in res:
    # find the differences in the sorted columns
    diffs = np.diff(arr, prepend=arr[0] - 501, append=arr[-1] + 501)
    
    # find the positions where both differences are above 500
    mask = (np.column_stack((diffs[:-1], diffs[1:])) > 500).all(1)
    
    # add the values in those position
    lookup.append(set(arr[mask]))

# filter the intervals by the criteria if any value in those that aren't within 500 of the nearest
res = [interval for interval in intervals if any(v in uni for v, uni in zip(interval, lookup))]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[[11000, 10250, 13000], [11000, 10500, 14000]]
```

Note that your current solution is `O(n^2)`.

#### Idea

The key idea is: sort the values of each *column* so verifying that the nearest values are above 500 can be done in `O(1)`.

Comment: Hi Dani, thanks for the answer. This solution works for smaller data sets, but once a set becomes large enough it begins to break down, I think it may have to do with the sorting of the columns. As the data sets I test get larger and more complex, the solution begins leaving out lists that should be in res.

Comment: @BenStewart Perhaps if you could create a small example where my solution fails I could help you

Comment: intervals = [[9000, 10000, 11000], [10000, 11000, 11000], [11000, 11000, 10250], [11000, 10250, 13000], [10250, 13000, 9250], [13000, 9250, 9750], [9250, 9750, 11250], [9750, 11250, 11000], [11250, 11000, 10500], [11000, 10500, 14000]]

Comment: [4351, 4235, 4523] is left out of the solution when it satisfies the unique qualifications

Comment: @BenStewart [4351, 4235, 4523] is not in the list of intervals that you posted in the message if I added to the list it appears